# How to 'ls' current directory (which is under svn) files info (path)?

Tags: bash, subversion

How can I sort of list current directory contents (including sub-directories  recursively) (which is under svn) files info (path relative to current dir)?

I want this to get log in format like:

```
none|main.lua
none|src/main.h
```

I wonder if it is possible and how to do such thing using svn and bash?

Comment: I want to create such log in order to create an image using [gource](http://code.google.com/p/gource/) that would represent actual state or current revision svn files. so I would just add `none` as user name,  0 as timestamp, A as type.

Comment: if it's just the relative path, have you considered using `find`? For the relative path, with `bash` you have [the globstar](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/internals/shell_options#globstar) (disabled by default, but just a `shopt -s globstar` away).

Comment: I don't understand whether you're trying to list all files in your working copy or just the files under svn, nor where the `none` comes from (why not a user name? and why do you mention a timestamp and a type in your comment, there aren't any in your sample output).

Comment: If you need this for gource, the wiki of gource has a page that explains how to use it with subversion http://code.google.com/p/gource/wiki/SVN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to start with something like:

```
find . -name .svn -prune -o -print
```

This prints out all the files under `.`, without traversing into any `.svn` directories.
I don't know what the `none|` part means, but you can pipe the output of `find` into `sed`, etc..

Another way is to start with

```
svn status -v
```

and filter the output as ncecssary.